# Align with bootstrap broken

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm finishing this website page, http://www.goldhairmoveis.com.br/bancos

But somehow the product alignment is broken.

All the configuration is the same for all divs and only this is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of the images (cadeiraopop.jpg) is 1px bigger than the rest.

The reason this is a problem, is the bootstrap alignment is done using css floats. So what is happening is the element starts and the oneside of the page and floats in the direction that you have specified (in this case, starts right, floats left). It continues to float until it hits something and then it stops. There for, you will need to ensure all images are the same height (preferably the same width as well.)

You can do this by manually editing the image size, or just use a css height attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much, i've inspected the previous and next images, but not the top one. Thanks again!